# Laravel Artisan not working at all after clone

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, git-clone

I have this weird situation: I've cloned all my repositories from github in a new local machine running Mac OsX some of them has Laravel framework installed but only some of these can execute the cmd `php artisan`.

I've tried to check permission on folders, uninstall/re-install composer and I've also tried to install a fresh version of Laravel. Another problem is that running the command doesn't output anything - no errors, nothing - only a new empty line of the terminal.

The only thing I know is that if I clone one of the repositories, then run `composer install` it throws `Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255`.

Thanks

---

## Update 1:

I've found running `composer install -vvv -o` that composer throw this error

```
Warning: require(/Users/USERNAME/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/USERNAME/laravel/artisan on line 16

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/USERNAME/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/USERNAME/laravel/artisan on line 16
```

---

## Update 2:

It seems that cmd `git clone` didn't copy that autoload file `bootstrap/autoload.php` for some reason that I don't understand at all.
I've imported the file manually from github and run, removed the `vendor` folder then run again `composer install --no-scripts` but still having the problem with artisan and if I run `composer update` it throw `Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 255`

Comment: Open your `composer.json` file and delete the `scripts` property/block (ensuring you don’t break the JSON syntax), then run `composer install`, then undo the changes to your `composer.json` file (restoring `scripts`).

Comment: @JAAulde is it the same of doing `composer install --no-scripts`???

Comment: TBH, This is just a workaround to a problem I’ve often had in new setups that I’ve never put the effort into solving. Once I get a successful install done once, I don’t see this pop up again. Obviously if it happens more to you than what I’ve described, running without scripts may not be a permanent solution given how useful the scripts can be for deployment and such.

Comment: @JAAulde lol, btw with `--no-scripts` it executes with no errors but then I'm still having the problem with artisan. Line 16 that is causing that error it's just a require... `require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

Comment: Well, hopefully someone with an actual grasp on this will come help you with an actual answer other than my silly hacking about. :)

Comment: @JAAulde yes, I hope too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-install laravel and copy files manually to make it works again.